# Using Case to sum NULL instances gives missing expression error

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm attempting to generate a list of vehicles that don't have a price or mileage listed using the below query. When I attempt to run the query, I get an error "ORA-00936: missing expression", but can't seem to find out why. From other posts here, I can see that using IS NULL should be the appropriate term for the WHEN portion, but I am not seeing anything wrong with the query itself. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Select
    SUM(CASE vehicles.mileage WHEN IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NO_MILEAGE,
    SUM(CASE vehicles.price WHEN IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NO_PRICE
From
    [data]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple syntax error:

```
Select
    SUM(CASE WHEN vehicles.mileage IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NO_MILEAGE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN vehicles.price   IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NO_PRICE
From
    [data];
```

This is assuming a table named `vehicles` in your `FROM` clause or a columns with an object or nested table type in `[data]` named `vehicles`. Else the qualification `vehicles.` would not make sense.

Use a "searched" `CASE` for a decision between two alternatives.

[Details about "simple" and "searched" `CASE` in the Oracle online reference.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm)

---

You can also use **`COUNT`** for your particular case. [The online reference again:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm)

> If you specify `expr`, then `COUNT` returns the number of rows where `expr` is not null.
>
> If you specify the asterisk (*), then this function returns all rows,
>   including duplicates and nulls. `COUNT` never returns null.

So you need the difference:

```
Select 
    COUNT(*) - COUNT(vehicles.mileage) AS NO_MILEAGE,
    COUNT(*) - COUNT(vehicles.price)   AS NO_PRICE
From
    [data];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Oracle's `NVL2` function:

```
Select
    SUM(NVL2(vehicles.mileage, 0, 1)) NO_MILEAGE,
    SUM(NVL2(vehicles.price, 0, 1)) NO_PRICE
From
    [data]
```